# How to empty a string and regenerate it, with the help of nested while loops and counter

Tags: python, while-loop, counter, nested-loops

I want to empty a string and want to regenerate the original string, when it required with the help of nested while loops and counter.

I have a large text file (code.txt) with thousands of similar codes but not in sequence, but for example let assume number of codes in file are only 7

let's say my txt file contains

```
xx01 xx02 xx03 xx03 xx03 xx03 xx03 xx01 xx04 xx04 xx02 xx04 xx04 xx04 xx02 xx03 xx04 xx07  xx05 xx06 xx07 xx04 xx05 xx06 xx07
```

First I will replace one of any code with 'Y'.

For example `xx03 = Y` (it will convert just single code, not all of xx03 will become Y), we have to choose first code otherwise it can't  do the original string back.

Now my file (code.txt) become or look like

```
xx01 xx02 Y xx03 xx03 xx03 xx03 xx01 xx04 xx04 xx02 xx04 xx04 xx04 xx02 xx03 xx04 xx07  xx05 xx06 xx07 xx04 xx05 xx06 xx07
```

Then I want to use a nested while loop (7 loops each for one code) with counter inside each other starting to pick the value 'Y'.

So after all operation we will get two files, In first file string will became (code.txt) = `xx01 xx02 Y` and in the second file (count.txt) will look like

```
loop number, count, for Example 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 7, 1,...
```

I tried the code but off course it's not working, someone can please modify/create it correctly so it can work properly.

```
with open('code.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
count = 0
word = 'y' # start with picking the Y or pointer at Y in the (code.txt)
while word = ' y xx01 '
    data = data.replace(' y xx01 , ' y ', 1)
    count = count.word(data)
    count += 1
    data =  +[1]
    print("loop 1", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
    print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
    count = 0
    while word = ' y xx02 '
        data = data.replace(' y xx02 , ' y ', 1)
        count = count.word(data)
        count += 1
        data =  +[1]
        print("loop 2", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
        print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
        count = 0
        while word = ' y xx03 '
            data = data.replace(' y xx03 , ' y ', 1)
            count = count.word(data)
            count = count.word(data)
            data =  +[1]
            print("loop 3", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
            print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
            count = 0
            while word = ' y xx04 '
                data = data.replace(' y xx04 , 'y', 1)
                count = count.word(data)
                count += 1
                data = +[1]
                print("loop 4", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
                print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
                count = 0
                while word = ' y xx05 '
                    data = data.replace(' y xx05 , 'y', 1)
                    count = count.word(data) 
                    count += 1d(data)
                    data = +[1]
                    print("loop 5", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
                    print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
                    count = 0
                    while word = ' y xx06 '
                        data = data.replace(' y xx06 , 'y', 1)
                        count = count.word(data)
                        count += 1
                        data = +[1]
                        print("loop 6", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
                        print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
                        count = 0
                        while word = ' y xx07 '
                            data = data.replace(' y xx07 , 'y', 1)
                            count = count.word(data)
                            count += 1
                            data = +[1]
                            print("loop 7", count, file=open('count.txt', 'a'))
                            print(data, file=open('code.txt', 'a'))
```

Comment: please format your question and abbreviate it where possible

Comment: modified.. as per your suggestion. Thanks